# Constraints for D3 mouse wheel zoom behaviour

Tags: javascript, zooming, d3.js

The d3 visualization library has a great mouse wheel and touch enabled zoom, however  there doesn't seem to be a way to constrain it. How could one patch the d3 zoom behavior to add min and max values?

Comment: You might ask on the D3 list, but looking at the [code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/zoom.js), there's no place to provide options here - you'd probably have to write your own behavior.

Comment: Thanks for that, ya I have a question in so far I only have others responding that they'd like the feature too. I've hacked around a bit but the zoom behavior is quite complex and I haven't had time to really sit down and study everything.

Comment: Yeah, it looks decidely non-trivial, in part because you can't just monkey-patch the existing behavior. Your best option is probably forking the code and putting max/min checks into `d3_behavior_zoomTo`.

Comment: Someone suggested porting over the http://polymaps.org/ zoom behavior so that could be a starting point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my [implementation of extents](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/345) for d3.behavior.zoom.

We can probably make it more flexible, but hopefully that'll get things started.

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks so much for that, be good to my 300 points :)

If others are looking for an example - until it is merged - checkout Jason's fork of d3 from github, switch to the zoom-extent branch and then open up `./examples/zoom-pan/zoom-pan-transform.html`

Comment: This is now merged into 2.5.0.